# Linq 2 SQL Convert to Outer Join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this linq to sql query that features several joins. I want to convert one of them to an outer join. The problem is that this query already has a from clause. How can I convert this query to use a left join on the OrderCertification table instead of an inner join?

The following query did not work (caused my app to crash):

```
var orderSummaries = from os in DbOrder.QueryOrderSummaries().Where(os => orders.Contains(os.OrderID))
   join o in dc.ORDERs on os.OrderID equals o.OrderID
   join oa in dc.ORDERADDRESSes on os.OrderID equals oa.OrderID
   join d in dc.vDoctors on o.DoctorID equals d.DoctorID
   join c in dc.ORDERCERTIFICATIONs on os.OrderID equals c.OrderID into oc
   from certification in oc.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new BatchOrderItem {
      OrderSummary = os,
      Order = o,
      ShipTo = oa,
      Prescriber = d,
      CertificationContact = certification
    };
```

Comment: When you say 'caused my app to crash', what was the exception?

Comment: @RufusL Never mind. This actually did work. The debugger was giving me an error because it couldn't find the AntiXSS library when I tried to debug my app with the modified code. I assumed this code was the issue because when I reverted the changes and rebuilt the app, it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is using `DefaultIfEmpty` to return all the rows from the first table. Check out this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: Check the example, I think it describes the solution better. But if I'm understanding what you want correctly, you would basically select all your other joins into one 'table' and then outer join OrderCertifactions on that table to get your result.